# Unable to transfer image using HTTP client

Tags: java, arrays, image, http, byte

I have an image byte array which I need to send to a servlet on a server using HTTP client.  We know how to send normal text data but unable to send the image data.

We created a string data from image byte array using the following code:

```
String imageData = new String(imagebyteArr);
```

And sent the above `String` to servlet through HTTP client, but when we again retrieve byte array from string using below code:

```
imageByteArr = imageData.toByteArray();
```

The resultant byte array is modified one, where in -127 is replaced on 63.

How to solve this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Strings get encoded. You have 2 posibilities: encode binary data as base64 (for example) send the base64 and decode on server side or binary upload with a PUT request.

Answer (score 1):

I would totally **discourage** you with taking image byte array and converting to `String` as you will have to worry about character encoding.

One thing to do is send the byte array directly using [`ByteArrayEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ByteArrayEntity.html), as follows:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(bytes));
post.setHeader("Content-type", ""application/octet-stream");
```

*Don't forget to set your `Content-Type` to the correct image appropriately.*